# How to add favicon.ico in ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, favicon

The solution structure of my application is:

[image]

Now I am in Login.aspx and I am willing to add favicon.ico, placed in the root, in that page.

What I am doing is:

```
<link id="Link1" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />  
<link id="Link2" runat="server" rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

Also I have tried:

```
<link id="Link1" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />  
<link id="Link2" runat="server" rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

But these aren't working.

I have cleared the browser cache but no luck.

What will be the path to the favicon.ico from:

- Login.aspx
- Site.master

Thank you.

---

The login page's URL: http://localhost:2873/Pages/Login.aspx and the favicon.ico's URL: http://localhost:2873/favicon.ico.

I am unable to see the favicon.ico [image] after changing my code as:

```
<link id="Link1" rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />  
<link id="Link2" rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

Comment: Can you visit http://localhost:2873/favicon.ico?

Comment: @ta.speot.is yes. it is there. I can visit and see the ico.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility suggests the `type` might be overkill.

Comment: @ta.speot.is If I use say: `<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />`, then it is working. but `<link href="http://localhost:2873/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />` not.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
/favicon.ico
```

might do the trick
I have tried this on my sample website

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/ows.ico" />
```

**Try this one in your site put the link in MasterPage,It works :)**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
```

I have tested in ,
**FireFox.**
[image]
**Chrome.**
[image]

**Opera.**
[image]

**Some troubleshoots:**
 1. Check if your favicon is accessible (correct url) ,goto view source and click on the favicon link

 2. Full refresh your browser by **Ctrl+F5** every time you make changes.
 3. Try searching from SO you may find your related problem here.

**Some Links to help you out:**
[Serving favicon.ico in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487230/serving-favicon-ico-in-asp-net-mvc)
[Favicon Not Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296038/favicon-not-showing)
[Why is favicon not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859431/why-is-favicon-not-visible)

Comment: The favicon.ico is there. Look at the image added.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have updated my question. `/favicon.ico` is not working :(

Comment: `~/favicon.ico` is also not working. If I firebug, then I see <link id="Link1" type="image/x-icon" href="../favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">.

Comment: If I use say: `<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />`, then it is working. but `<link href="http://localhost:2873/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />` not.

Comment: Hey Topas relax a bit,try suggestions in my answers one by one,Itz working for me it WILL for you also :)

Comment: Horrible :) Firefox's cache was creating the problem. After deleting it DO work. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for links, first links helped a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue. My url is as below

```
http://somesite/someapplication
```

Below doesnot work

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I got it to work like below

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/someapplication/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: @user3308043 - I am sorry that you find my answer ridiculous.. but I just posted the exact things what I did to solve my problem.. this solution went into production and from past one year it is working fine.. and more over I never and ever said dotNetSoldier's answer is wrong. I justed posted one of the solution that I had... I never said others answer are wrong

Answer (score 4):

resolve the url like this `href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/favicon.ico")%>"`

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/favicon.ico")%>'>

Answer (score 4):

```html
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
```

This worked for me. If anyone is troubleshooting while reading this - I found issues when my favicon.ico was not nested in the root folder. I had mine in the Resources folder and was struggling at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
/favicon.ico
```

The leading slash is important.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have updated my question. /favicon.ico is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

@Scripts.Render("~/favicon.ico");
Please try above code at the bottom of your Layout file in MVC

Answer (score 1):

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/images/")favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/ >
```

This works for me in MVC4 application favicon image is placed in the images folder and it will traverse from root directory to images and find favicon.ico bingo!

Answer (score 0):

for me, it didn't work without specifying the MIME in web.config, under `<system.webServer><staticContent>`

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your favicon.ico is 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 or 64x64 ...
506x478 for example will not work.

Comment: While this is useful information, it doesn't answer the original question regarding ASP.NET, and would be better suited as a comment.